# How to get rid of text connected in with the Table of Contents for Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am just learning how to do Table of Contents and Styles.  As I was marking or clicking on the Heading 1 and Heading 2 Styles, I noticed that when I generated a Table of Contents, that on Heading 2 it included part of the text (or paragraph) in the Table of Contents.  I only want the subheading.  How do I modify Heading 2 to get rid of the paragraph text and it just generate the subheading?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize what level of headings are picked up by the ToC. See [Here](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-and-customize-a-table-of-contents-3ae33d41-0fc5-4758-9904-3d2bf81632b9).

In your case, you probably have to exclude some levels from the ToC